# export page of phpmyadmin goes blank after update php5 to php7.0

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I had php5-fpm, nginx, mysql, phpmyadmin that installed on my ubuntu 14.04. every thing was good. When I updated php to php7.0 phpmyadmin required to install mbstring. I installed it and works well. But Export page of phpmyadmin show blank page.

This error is logged in nginx error log file.

```
2016/08/09 16:20:31 [error] 1494#0: *35 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot 'break' 2 levels in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php on line 864" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /phpmyadmin/export.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=584932884866cc16a2444d67eb7927d0&phpMyAdmin=4aro5gojhjuli0svkuctbrlot0450dar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by modifying line 864 in phpmyadmin/export.php, change :

```
break 2;

By:

break;
```

Solution provided by **bbalent** in the following [answer](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11912):

> Don't worry, this is a code mistake from the phpMyAdmin team: you are
>   into one loop and not two nested loops. That's why you can't "break 2"
>   (because 2 denotes that you're inside a nested loop). The error
>   appears because PHP7 is stricter than former versions. By the way,
>   this can fix other packages (PHPExcel, newer versions of phpMyAdmin
>   etc.). Most of the time, the developper deleted the nested loop and
>   forgot to update this line of code.

Comment: Line 861 for me, but an otherwise perfect answer - thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was in line 604, and it works. Thank you very much

```
if ($GLOBALS[$what . '_structure_or_data'] == 'structure' || $GLOBALS[$what . '_structure_or_data'] == 'structure_and_data') {
        if (!PMA_exportStructure($db, $table, $crlf, $err_url, $do_relation, $do_comments, $do_mime, $do_dates, 'triggers', $export_type)) {
            break;
        }
```